# what's the formal name for this algorithm problem

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of integers, let's say N1 N2 ... Nn, and a given integer X, the problem is put as:
is it possible to select  all or some of the integers from the list that the sum of the selected integers equal to X.

I think is should be a common problem that already got a formal "term name", which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) , although technically that is defined in terms of a *set* rather than a list.

Answer (score 4):

[Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). An example of [NP Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problem.